# Math in Russian. hi, i want to learn math for programming. BUT my main language is russian

Tags: self-learning

I am not very good at English, but I was able to complete the cs50 course (on English full). And, I realized that without mathematics it would be difficult to read the proof of algorithms, and generally develop as a programmer (to be a good developer). I googled and found books like: AoPS Prealgebra, AoPS introduction to algebra by Richard Rusczyk. And I think that it will take me more time to translate than the tasks themselves (not sure). So I wanted to ask if there are analogues of the same books.

Comment: Maybe you will have more luck if you ask on r/math (reddit)

Comment: Agreed with Tryst. For better or for worse the stackExchange sites are predominantly English-only, a less formal forum such as Reddit would likely handle this question better

Comment: Usually, the mathematics proposed to applied computer scientists belong to a category which is not adequately decribed by the keyword **algebra** but by the better keyword "**discrete mathematics**" (one could argue a long time on what is the frontier of such a category) including (a little advanced) arithmetic (with base 2, 4,16, numeration issues), graph theory, linear algebra, combinatorics, basic probability, complex numbers, some abstract algebra, like the beginning of group theory, etc.